# Proof of Van der Corput Lemma

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I was asked to show the Van der Corput Lemma:

Let $I=[a,b]\subset\mathbb{R}$. If $f\in C^2(I\to\mathbb{R})$ is either convex or concave, and $|f'(x)| \geq \lambda$ for all $x\in I$ and some $\lambda>0$, establish the estimate
\begin{equation}
\left| \int_I e^{if(x)} \,dx \right| \leq \frac{2}{\lambda}.
\end{equation}
Using
\begin{equation}
e^{if(x)}=\frac{1}{if'(x)} \frac{d}{dx} e^{if(x)}
\end{equation}
I substituted into the integral and integrated by parts to obtain
\begin{equation}
\left| \int_I e^{if(x)} \,dx \right| \leq \frac{1}{|f'(b)|} + \frac{1}{|f'(a)|} + \int_a^b \left| \frac{d}{dx} \left( \frac{1}{f'(x)} \right) \right| \,dx \leq \frac{2}{\lambda} + \int_a^b \left| \frac{d}{dx} \left( \frac{1}{f'(x)} \right) \right| \,dx.
\end{equation}
Then I don't know what to do next. Is the integral supposed to be $0$? How can I use the concavity and convexity of the function?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{f'(x)}\right)$ has a constant sign so
$$\int_a^b\left\vert\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{f'(x)}\right)\right\vert dx=
\left\vert \int_a^b
\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{f'(x)}\right)dx\right\vert
=\left\vert \frac{1}{f'(b)}-\frac{1}{f'(a)}\right\vert$$
So,
$$\left\vert \int_a^b e^{if(x)}dx\right\vert\leq \frac{1}{|f'(b)|}+
\frac{1}{|f'(a)|}+ \left\vert \frac{1}{f'(b)}-\frac{1}{f'(a)}\right\vert
=2\max\left(\frac{1}{|f'(a)|},\frac{1}{|f'(b)|}\right)\leq\frac{2}{\lambda}$$

Comment: Can you please explain the last equality?

Comment: @dh87 Considering cases $x\ge y$ and $x<y$, we see easily that $2\max(x,y)=x+y+|x-y|$